# JavaScript formatting lost when table is resorted

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have the follow code applied to a SharePoint list.  I'm replacing the text in the second column with a KPI.  Everything works great until another script is called on the page like resorting a column.  How can I rerun my script after any other code on the page is called?

```
function updateTableKPIs() {
var prtbl = document.getElementById('{EF4B2750-DD8E-4A81-BFB9-7DC4CD29441A}-{EB96600B-725C-4C9B-B595-BAF51F6CAA21}');
var tbllen = prtbl.rows.length;
    for(var i=1; i < tbllen; i++){
        var level = '';
        var level = prtbl.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
        var pjstatus = '';
        switch(level){
            case 'In Progress':
                pjstatus = 'green';
                break;
            case 'Off Track':
                pjstatus = 'firebrick';
                break;  
            case 'Completed':
                pjstatus = 'steelblue';
                break;                  
            default:
                pjstatus = 'silver';
        }
        prtbl.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = '<div style="background-color:' + pjstatus + ';height:20px;width:20px;border-radius:50px;margin:auto;"></div>';

    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', updateTableKPIs);
```

Example - Before and after sorting the Title column:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this.  I ran across the following article about client side rendering in SharePoint. Andrei Markeev does an excellent job of outlining how to use CSR.
[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

Below is my updated code.  Hopefully someone else can use this as well if they want to use KPIs in their lists.

```
function updateTableKPIs() {
var prtbl = document.getElementById('{EF4B2750-DD8E-4A81-BFB9-7DC4CD29441A}-{EB96600B-725C-4C9B-B595-BAF51F6CAA21}');
var tbllen = prtbl.rows.length;
    for(var i=1; i < tbllen; i++){
        var level = '';
        var level = prtbl.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
        var pjstatus = '';
        switch(level){
            case 'In Progress':
                pjstatus = 'green';
                break;
            case 'At Risk':
                pjstatus = 'orange';
                break;              
            case 'Off Track':
                pjstatus = 'firebrick';
                break;  
            case 'Completed':
                pjstatus = 'steelblue';
                break;  
            case 'Backlog':
                pjstatus = 'silver';
                break;                  
            default:
                pjstatus = '';
        }
        prtbl.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML = '<div style="background-color:' + pjstatus + ';height:20px;width:20px;border-radius:50px;margin:auto;"></div>';

    }
}

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
        updateTableKPIs();
  }
});
```